# Git update master content on Github

Tags: git, github

I would like to use Git to save and share my work on github and use it from anywhere.

I had just a master branch with my script `GaussianMixture.py` and a `readme.md`

I was working on new functions on my script and I accidentally pushed the commit of this modified script (`GaussianMixture_priors_all_init.py`) in the master branch. I wanted to create a new branch.

I succeed to move this script from master to a new branch I created (`priors_all_inits`) \o/ with :

```
git branch priors_all_inits
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git checkout priors_all_inits
git push -u origin priors_all_inits
```

Now when I check the content of my master branch and my new branch I have :

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only priors_all_inits 
GaussianMixture.py
GaussianMixture_priors_all_init.py
README.md

git ls-tree -r --name-only master
GaussianMixture.py
README.md
```

Is that normal that my original script GaussianMixture.py and my readme.md are also copy in my new branch `priors_all_inits` ? (let's say it's normal...)

WHY on github, my modified script `GaussianMixture_priors_all_init.py` is in the master AND in the priors_all_inits branch ? How can I update my master to have the same thing that I see in local on github. **Because on Github, my master and my branch are exactly the same with the same content...**

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you `git push origin HEAD -f` to GitHub afterwards?

Comment: Now I did and it doesn't change anything on github, master and branch are still identical

Comment: Better be specific and specify the full refspec to be safe:
`git push -f origin master:master`

This would mean "push the local master branch to the remote master branch". While just `git push -f origin HEAD` would push the current branch to the remote (and at the end of your example, the master branch is not your current branch).

Comment: thank you that was the good solution !